# How to troubleshoot a regularly crashing Google Play?

Tags: google-play-services, crashes

I'm using a Lineage OS custom ROM on a Xiaomi Redmi 4A. I can't remember when it started, but quite often, I see a message telling me that "Google Play has stopped working".

This can happen on the launcher screen, or while using an app. I have seen it happen in all apps I use regularly. It happened around 6 times while I was writing this post, but the frequency varies.

I have installed a Logcat Reader application, and captured the log after a crash. This is what I think is the relevant part:

```
[07-24 15:26:38.492 2654:2699 F/libc]
invalid address or address of corrupt block 0x78 passed to dlfree

[07-24 15:26:38.492 2654:2699 F/libc]
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0xdeadbaad in tid 2699 (bgExecutor #2)

[07-24 15:26:38.602 708:708 F/DEBUG]
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***

[07-24 15:26:38.602 708:708 F/DEBUG]
LineageOS Version: '13.0-20170307-UNOFFICIAL-rolex'

[07-24 15:26:38.603 708:708 F/DEBUG]
Build fingerprint: 'Xiaomi/lineage_rolex/rolex:6.0.1/MOB31K/fc38c175e6:userdebug/test-keys'

[07-24 15:26:38.603 708:708 F/DEBUG]
Revision: '0'

[07-24 15:26:38.603 708:708 F/DEBUG]
ABI: 'arm'

[07-24 15:26:38.603 708:708 F/DEBUG]
pid: 2654, tid: 2699, name: bgExecutor #2  >>> com.android.vending <<<

[07-24 15:26:38.603 708:708 F/DEBUG]
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0xdeadbaad

[07-24 15:26:38.650 708:708 F/DEBUG]
Abort message: 'invalid address or address of corrupt block 0x78 passed to dlfree'

[07-24 15:26:38.650 708:708 F/DEBUG]
    r0 00000000  r1 00000000  r2 00000000  r3 00000002

[07-24 15:26:38.651 708:708 F/DEBUG]
    r4 00000078  r5 deadbaad  r6 f7073f38  r7 ab33a000

[07-24 15:26:38.651 708:708 F/DEBUG]
    r8 00000080  r9 dccd2afc  sl f6fd58db  fp f6fd58e4

[07-24 15:26:38.651 708:708 F/DEBUG]
    ip f706e5d8  sp dccd29e8  lr f703fc6d  pc f703fc6c  cpsr 600f0030

[07-24 15:26:38.658 708:708 F/DEBUG]

backtrace:

[07-24 15:26:38.658 708:708 F/DEBUG]
    #00 pc 00030c6c  /system/lib/libc.so (dlfree+1287)

[07-24 15:26:38.658 708:708 F/DEBUG]
    #01 pc 000157cd  /system/lib/libandroidfw.so (_ZN7android13ResStringPool6uninitEv+38)

[07-24 15:26:38.658 708:708 F/DEBUG]
    #02 pc 0001651d  /system/lib/libandroidfw.so (_ZN7android10ResXMLTree6uninitEv+14)

[07-24 15:26:38.659 708:708 F/DEBUG]
    #03 pc 0001653b  /system/lib/libandroidfw.so (_ZN7android10ResXMLTreeD1Ev+4)

[07-24 15:26:38.659 708:708 F/DEBUG]
    #04 pc 00013267  /system/lib/libandroidfw.so (_ZN7android12AssetManager10getPkgNameEPKc+258)

[07-24 15:26:38.659 708:708 F/DEBUG]
    #05 pc 000132c3  /system/lib/libandroidfw.so (_ZN7android12AssetManager18getBasePackageNameEj+62)

[07-24 15:26:38.659 708:708 F/DEBUG]
    #06 pc 0008894b  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so

[07-24 15:26:38.659 708:708 F/DEBUG]
    #07 pc 726cc6e1  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot.oat (offset 0x1f93000)

[07-24 15:26:39.752 708:708 F/DEBUG]

Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_06

[07-24 15:26:39.752 708:708 E/DEBUG]
AM write failed: Broken pipe
```

I have tried to wipe the dalvik cache partition, as well as reinstalling Google Play from opengapps.org. Neither fixed the problem.

What should I do to work towards fixing this?

Comment: On which device does this occur? Is the device rooted and/or is a custom ROM installed?

Comment: @Robert This is a Xiaomi Redmi 4A, with a LineageOS custom ROM installed.

Answer (score 0):

When installing Open GApps on Lineage OS, it **must** be flashed together with the Rom. Installing GApps after flashing the rom and booting the phone cause crashes. If you want to use Open GApps with Lineage OS, download both and place them in the memory and first flash the rom zip file. Without exiting the rom flash GApps zip and boot the phone. At the firts boot, you will be asked to configure your google logins and then GApps can be used.

Read installation instructions on [LineageOS wiki](https://wiki.lineageos.org/gapps.html#installation)

Comment: Hmm, this might be a thing I did wrong back when I flashed this ROM. What would be the best way of backing up the data before a factory reset? I've heard of NANDroid as a good, comprehensive backup, but I'd think that it would also restore the erroneous state that creates these crashes.

Comment: What is the recovery you currently on? TWRP or CWM? They provide recovery/backup tools too. Read [this](https://www.xda-developers.com/how-to-backup-android) article on XDA or [this](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=853020) thread for some comparison.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am currently using TWRP. However, a too-comprehensive backup might, ironically, be a problem. The crashes must be caused by an some incorrect data stored somewhere by something. Therefore, restoring absolutely all data, of all apps, would restore the crashes too. How can I make sure I don't "overshoot"?

Comment: I suggest trial and error